# importing python packages sometimes fails raising ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, package, python-import

It is an already asked questions but still I'm not able to solve it and understand it.

I install python packages with pip, and I use Visual Studio.

My python packages are installed in:

c:\users\max\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages

both those that can be imported and those that somehow fail and raise an error.

In my case pycountry_convert and scikit-bio packages raise ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Why? What should I do to make them work? Thanks.

UPDATE:

I use pip list -v to check packages installed, but if I manually go inside the folder I cannot see these packages.

Comment: Can you please verify manually that these packages are installed in `c:\users\max\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages` with proper files in it?

Comment: @AsadullahNaeem Thanks, I added an update in my question. If I go in the folder I cannot see any of these 2 packages, that's strange

Comment: are you working in a virtual environment?

Comment: @AsadullahNaeem no

Comment: you can have two Pythons installed and you install module in one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't share modules. If you run code with `python.exe` then you can use the same `python.exe -m pip install ...` to install modules for this Python.

Comment: @furas that makes sense, but I can see only one python installed in my system

Comment: when you run code then you can check `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python.exe` and later use `/full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install ... ` and check `/full/path/to/python.exe -m pill list -v`

Comment: @furas yes, it worked, thank you! Can you please explain why? If you want you can make an answer and I will accept it

Comment: this problem was many times on Stackoverflow. You may have two Pythons installed and `pip` (without full path) may install modules for one Python but `python.exe` (without full path) may run other Python. Sometimes you can see different version number when you run `pip -V` and `python -V` (upper `V`) and this shows that default `pip` installs for wrong Python. On Linux this not make so big problem because it usually keep only one copy of every version (it rather don't install two Python with the same version) and you can use `pip3.10` and `python3.10` to run the same `python 3.10`